# What are $r(\Lambda)$ and $s(\Lambda)$?

Tags: graph-theory, notation, algebraic-graph-theory

[Proposition 7.2](http://books.google.com/books?id=6TasRmIFOxQC&pg=PA44) in Biggs Algebraic Graph Theory book says that $$\det A=\sum (-1)^{r(\Lambda)} 2^{s(\Lambda)},$$
where $A$ is the adjacency matrix of a graph $\Gamma$ and the summation is over all spanning elementary subgraphs $\Lambda$ of $\Gamma$.

What are $r(\Lambda)$ and $s(\Lambda)$? I swear this Biggs guy has not defined them.

Comment: See the top answer to this question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/134956/determinants-in-graph-theory

Answer (score 3):

These are the rank and co-rank respectively. If $G$ is a graph with $n$ vertices $m$ edges and $c$ connected components then

$$r(G) = n -c \quad \mbox{and} \quad s(G) = m-n+c.$$

Note that  Biggs actually defines them in his book - see [page 25](http://books.google.com/books?id=6TasRmIFOxQC&pg=PA25) of the second edition.